# One liner to find maximum from array in php for associative array

Tags: php

I looked at the question for maximum from associative array but I am looking for one liner. I have array like following,

```
    $studenRsults=array(
  array(
      'roll'=>1,
      'name'=>'jack Smit',
      'marks'=>70
  ),

    array(
      'roll'=>4,
      'name'=>'Sita',
      'marks'=>50
  ),
   array(
      'roll'=>2,
      'name'=>'Akhilesh',
      'marks'=>80
  ),
  array(
      'roll'=>3,
      'name'=>'jon',
      'marks'=>50
  ),
);
```

Please suggest one liner thanks.

Comment: Why must it be a "one liner"? Code's quality and readability is not measured in the number of lines it takes to complete.

Comment: show what you've accomplished so far, please.

Comment: I want to die peacefully in my sleep like my grandfather, not screaming in terror like his passengers.

Comment: Actually I had a big forloop running and I made a separate function to make it work. However I want to further reduce the code with already existing function or php functions. That was why I was looking for this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs php 5.5+ for [array_column](http://php.net/array_column)

```
$max = max(array_column($studenRsults, 'marks'));
```

or php 5.3+ for lamdas

```
$max = max(array_map(function($el){ return $el['marks']; }, $studenRsults));
```

Comment: That was brilliant. I never thought I can make a function inside array map. Thanks a lot mate..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean max of roll. But yeah, code quality isn't measured in how few lines you have...

```
foreach($studenRsults as $result) $maxResult = (isset($maxResult['roll']) && ($maxResult['roll'] > $result['roll'])) ? $maxResult : $result;

print_r($maxResult); // print the max roll student
```

Comment: I did not mean writting it in one line. anyways thanks for help